# Hyperlinks in CTaskDialog footer

Tags: hyperlink, mfc, taskdialog

I have read this article:

[Article](http://www.nuonsoft.com/blog/2009/06/10/ctaskdialog-in-mfc-in-visual-c-2010/)

[image: Sample]

It clearly shows hyperlinks are supported in the footer. I can’t work out how to do it. I don’t want a literal URL in the text but other text that hyperlinks to a help article in the program.

Comment: Have you tried just HTML? `SetFooterText(LR"(Footer information for the <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">dialog</a>.)");`

Comment: @acraig5075 That does indeed create a hyperlink. Thank you. However, I now realise I can't use this approach because it would be linking to a topic in a CHM file.

Comment: I suspect if you handle the click with [CTaskDialog::OnHyperlinkClick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctaskdialog-class?view=vs-2017#onhyperlinkclick) then you should be able to call `AfxGetApp()->HtmlHelp(...)` accordingly.

Comment: @acraig5075 So you are suggesting I inherit my own task dialog class so that I can override this handler. OK ...

Comment: @acraig5075 Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CMyTaskDialog.h"

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CMyTaskDialog, CTaskDialog)


CMyTaskDialog::CMyTaskDialog(_In_ const CString& strContent, 
                             _In_ const CString& strMainInstruction, 
                             _In_ const CString& strTitle,
                             _In_ int nCommonButtons,
                             _In_ int nTaskDialogOptions, _In_ const CString& strFooter)
    : CTaskDialog(strContent, strMainInstruction, strTitle, nCommonButtons, nTaskDialogOptions, strFooter)
{
}


CMyTaskDialog::~CMyTaskDialog()
{
}




HRESULT CMyTaskDialog::OnHyperlinkClick(const CString& strHref)
{
    HWND hwnd =
        HtmlHelp(
            GetDesktopWindow(),
            _T("d:\\MeetSchedAssist.chm::/") + strHref,
            HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC,
            NULL);

    return S_OK;
}
```

However, there are two issues still:

1. `CTaskDialog` does not have a `GetSafeHWnd` API call so I don't know how to set it as the parent.
2. The `OnHyperlinkClick` is generic so if you have multiple links on the task dialog you might have to test the phrase to decide how you want to handle it.

Comment: No `GetSafeHwnd` - that's just a limitation of the MFC interface. Underlying callback interface passes the `HWND`. Try to override [CTaskDialog::TaskDialogCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctaskdialog-class?view=vs-2017#taskdialogcallback). Check `uNotification == TDN_HYPERLINK_CLICKED`.

Comment: @zett42 I am sorry but I have failed at overriding this callback friend method.

Comment: It propably is a static method so you can't override it. When MFC gets in the way like this, you always have the option to use the API directly, [here is an example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appplatform/taskdialogs/TaskDialogSDKSample.cpp).

Comment: @zett42 Thanks. I have gone another route not using `CTaskDialog` so this is a moot point now. But we can leave the answer there as someone may have use of it.